# MySQL server don´t start after trying to update to php 7.4

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-platform, debian, google-compute-engine

I tried to update PHP 7.0 to 7.4 on Debian in Google Cloud instance, and now MySQL server is not working.

I received this message when i try to update :

```
Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
 mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
 mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

And this message when I try to restart MySQL server :

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl status mysql.service :

```
●mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-02-13 06:08:00 UTC; 5min ago
  Process: 8606 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 8571 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
 mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
 mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
 Stopped MySQL Community Server.
 mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
 Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
 mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
 mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is what i get with journalctl -xe :

```
Feb 13 06:26:07 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9471]: Received disconnect from 194.5.192.228 port 40696:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:07 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9471]: Disconnected from 194.5.192.228 port 40696 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:07 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9469]: Received disconnect from 81.68.143.165 port 33030:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:07 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9469]: Disconnected from 81.68.143.165 port 33030 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:09 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9463]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.185 port 39448 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:10 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: Invalid user csx from 104.248.42.186 port 40838
Feb 13 06:26:10 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: input_userauth_request: invalid user csx [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:10 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 13 06:26:10 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=104.248.42.186
Feb 13 06:26:12 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9463]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.185 port 39448 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:12 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9463]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 218.92.0.185 port 39448 ssh2 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:12 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9463]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:12 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9463]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.185  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:12 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9463]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Feb 13 06:26:13 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: Failed password for invalid user csx from 104.248.42.186 port 40838 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:13 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: Received disconnect from 104.248.42.186 port 40838:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:13 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9473]: Disconnected from 104.248.42.186 port 40838 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:16 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9475]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.185  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:18 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9475]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.185 port 11686 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:20 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9475]: Received disconnect from 218.92.0.185 port 11686:11:  [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:20 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9475]: Disconnected from 218.92.0.185 port 11686 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:24 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.131.165.85  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:27 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 10496 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:29 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 10496 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:32 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 10496 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:32 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: Received disconnect from 221.131.165.85 port 10496:11:  [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:32 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: Disconnected from 221.131.165.85 port 10496 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:32 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9477]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.131.165.85  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:34 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.131.165.85  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:36 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 49207 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:38 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: Invalid user sudo1 from 139.210.98.218 port 58261
Feb 13 06:26:38 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: input_userauth_request: invalid user sudo1 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:38 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 13 06:26:38 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=139.210.98.218
Feb 13 06:26:39 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 49207 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:39 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: Failed password for invalid user sudo1 from 139.210.98.218 port 58261 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:40 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: Received disconnect from 139.210.98.218 port 58261:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:40 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9481]: Disconnected from 139.210.98.218 port 58261 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:42 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 49207 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:42 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: Received disconnect from 221.131.165.85 port 49207:11:  [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:42 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: Disconnected from 221.131.165.85 port 49207 [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:42 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9479]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.131.165.85  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:44 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9483]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.131.165.85  user=root
Feb 13 06:26:46 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9483]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 55794 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:48 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9483]: Failed password for root from 221.131.165.85 port 55794 ssh2
Feb 13 06:26:49 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9485]: Invalid user zsd from 61.80.179.118 port 43812
Feb 13 06:26:49 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9485]: input_userauth_request: invalid user zsd [preauth]
Feb 13 06:26:49 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9485]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 13 06:26:49 spain-en-la-nube-vm sshd[9485]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=61.80.179.118
```

It seems like there are a lot of attemps to login to the MySQL, but that is not the problem, the problem started when I tryed to update the version of php.
I was following a post that explain how to do it, so i put this commands :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and I received errors and after that MySQL is not working. I have tryed all solutions that I have found about this problem, but no one works, and don´t know what to do, please if anybody can help i will be very gratefull. Thanks

This is the version : Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch) Release: 9.13

Comment: The answer is probably here: "See `systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` Why is that information not in your question?

Comment: Did you first check to make sure the version of Debian and the version of MySQL support PHP 7.4? PHP 7.0 was release 12/2015 which makes your system about five years behind.

Comment: I just would like to make it work again, as the website is showing a message Error establishing a database connection

Comment: Please @JohnHanley any idea what can I do? Thanks

Comment: The logs that you posted are about ssh. Find the log entries for MySQL.

Comment: Where is it located? Do you know the route?

Comment: Let me suggest that you Google search on how to debug MySQL.

Comment: I have done lots of research, already more than 10 hours trying to fix this problem, following tutorials, but I don´t find a solution. I guess that for someone with the knowledge maybe could be a question of minutes to fix it, but I don´t have knowledge about MySQL server and Linux. Could you please help me? @JhonHanley

Comment: I recommend that you move your question to one of the Stackexchange sites on Linux. This is a programming site and I write software that interfaces with MySQL. https://stackexchange.com/sites One tip. Review the beginning of the logs. Make sure you system is not running out of disk space or another simple to fix problem. You will have to learn how to read your system's logfiles as they are too big to post on forums.

Comment: Are you sure this is in any way related to PHP? Usually, updating PHP won't cause a MySQL server to fail

Answer (score 0):

Looks like from after 17th June of 2017 Debian moved from mysql to mariadb by [default](https://mariadb.com/newsroom/press-releases/mariadb-replaces-mysql-as-the-default-in-debian-9/#:%7E:text=Released%20on%20June%2017%2C%202017,database%20to%20MariaDB%20from%20MySQL.) in the repositories, so it seems that you have a package issue.

I would try to install

> mariadb-server

package and see if it works properly. And I am unsure if you have run the following command:

```
apt -f install
```

Just to see if apt complains about any other package.